# get_channel not working in tasks.loop() discord python

Tags: python, loops, asynchronous, discord

I have been having a problem with get_channel function. I want bot to give me list of users on given channel every 60 seconds(5 seconds for test). After i run code i don't get any response, no exception rises but even the print before the function isn't written not mentioning get_channel response.

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=get_prefix, intents=discord.Intents.all(), help_command = None)
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.tree.sync()       
    change_status.start()
    get_users.start()
```

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def get_users(ctx):
    channel = client.get_channel(1082719335375720448)
    print(channel.members)
    await ctx.send(channel)
```

I have gone through lot of possible solutions like enabling all intents, trying to use "await asyncio.sleep(1)" nothing worked out. I know that get_channels will only work when the bot is ready so i noticed that code like below works but it isn't wanted loop.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(1082719335375720448)
    print(channel.members)
    print("Bot is connected to discord")
    await client.tree.sync()  
    channel = client.get_channel(1082719335375720448)
    print(channel.members)  
    change_status.start()
    get_users.start()
```

One more thing I noticed is that second call with get_channel included in code above actually worked and after one try it stopped working, that surprised me and don't know what could happen(i wasn't changing code just running twice)

Answer (score 0):

`get_channel` only works if the channel is in the client's cache. It's not guaranteed to be so we could use `fetch` to get the channel as well.

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def get_users(ctx):
    channel = client.get_channel(1082719335375720448)
    if not channel:
        # get_channel didn't find it
        channel = await client.fetch_channel(1082719335375720448)
```

This only uses `fetch` if it couldn't find the channel in the local cache.

Answer (score 0):

So... I found out what was wrong. I didn't mention in my question that I also used other `tasks.loop()` while running `get_users` loop and from what I've read you can't run two loops simultaneously unless you use `asyncio.gather()`.

```
 @client.event
 async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is connected to discord")             
    await asyncio.gather(change_status(), get_users())

 #second loop I didn't mention 
 @tasks.loop(seconds=5)
 async def change_status():
    await client.change_presence(activity = discord.Game(next(bot_status)))

 #loop I wanted to run
 @tasks.loop(seconds=10)
 async def get_users():
    channel = client.get_channel(id)
    print(channel)
```

Thank you ESloman for you help, your code works fine but unfortunately problem lied somewhere else :)